# System Usage Requirements

Tags: command-line, server

I need to get total of disk space with used space and similarly total ram and used ram in json format and send a post request to api. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a script like the following. First, the values:

```
disk_total=$(df | grep "/$" | awk '{print $2;}')
disk_used=$(df | grep "/$" | awk '{print $3;}')
```

This uses the list of mounted devices (`df`) and selects just the disk mounted at `/`, assuming that that is the disk that we are interested in. For cases where more partitions on the same disk may be mounted, I can't give a general solution. From that line, it takes the second and third fields for the total disk space and used disk space, respectively, and assigns these to variables `disk_total` and `disk_used`.

```
mem_total=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $2;}')
mem_used=$(free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3;}')
```

This does the same for memory measurements, using the `free` command.

Now that we have the values in variables, you can output json like this:

```
echo "    myjson = {disk_total: $disk_total,"       \
     "              disk_used: $disk_used,  "       \
     "              mem_total: $mem_total,  "       \
     "              mem_used: $mem_used     "       \
     "             }"
```